# Add property for list object in loop and return this object, but it was not applied

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I use sequlize in node, and I have to implemented that add property in list object from sequlize querying.

```
member.findAll({
    where:{
        isPartner:1
    }
}).then(partnerList => {
    for(let i = 0; i<partnerList.length; i++){
        const partner_no = partnerList[i].dataValues.no;
        partner.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: member,
                required: true,
            }],
            where:{
                partner_no : partner_no
            }
        }).then(myCustomers => {
            partnerList[i].dataValues.myCustomers = myCustomers.length;

        })
    }
    return partnerList;
}).then(partnerList => {
    res.render('partner/partners', {partnerList: partnerList})
})
```

I expect get object added 'myCustomers' property, but all attribute in list is not contain this property.

Why is this? How can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `return partnerList` happens before you add you properties. If you can use async/await it makes this sort thing much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`partner.findAll` is asynchronous. When your code goes through the loop and initializes the promises, the requests have only just been sent out; `.then`s only resolve *after* the thread that initialized them has completed, so `partnerList` does not get populated before you `return partnerList`. Instead, use `Promise.all` over all `findAll`s:

```
member.findAll({
  where:{
    isPartner:1
  }
}).then(async (partnerList) => {
  await Promise.all(partnerList.map(({ dataValues: { no } }) => (
    partner.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: member,
        required: true,
      }],
      where:{
        partner_no : no
      }
    }).then(myCustomers => {
      partnerList[i].dataValues.myCustomers = myCustomers.length;
    }))));
  return partnerList;
}).then(partnerList => {
  res.render('partner/partners', {partnerList: partnerList})
})
```

But with `async`/`await`, it'll be easier to read without `.then`s:

```
const partnerList = await member.findAll({
  where:{
    isPartner:1
  }
});
await Promise.all(partnerList.map(async ({ dataValues: { no } }) => {
  const myCustomers = await partner.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: member,
      required: true,
    }],
    where:{
      partner_no : partner_no
    }
  });
  partner.dataValues.myCustomers = myCustomers.length;
}));
res.render('partner/partners', {partnerList: partnerList});
```